# different Timestamps when using strtotime() in PHP and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli, timestamp

I have a date stored in the database. The date is 2017-03-01. The field is a "date"-field.

When I use

```
DATE_FORMAT(orderdate, '%d.%m.%Y') as mydate
```

in my MySQL-Query, "01.03.2017" is displayed.

When I use

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orderdate) as mydate
```

and output it like `date('d.m.Y', $mydate)`

I get 28.02.2017 as a result.

Is this a "February-Problem"? How can I make date() do it right?

----------------- Edit 1 -----------------

I put this in my code already before.

```
# set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna');

# daylight-saving time
if(date('I') < 1){
 mysqli_query($db, "SET time_zone = '+01:00'");
}else{
 mysqli_query($db, "SET time_zone = '+02:00'");
}
```

----------------- Edit 2 -----------------

Ok, I generated a MySQL-Table with this Content (Field-Type: "date"):

```
xdate
2017-01-01
2017-01-15
2017-01-31
2017-02-01
2017-02-15
2017-02-28
2017-03-01
2017-03-15
2017-03-31
2017-04-01
2017-04-15
2017-04-30
2017-05-01
2017-05-15
2017-05-31
2017-06-01
2017-06-15
```

Generated Output from my Script:

```
Current Time
2017-06-16 02:31:08 PHP-Time
2017-06-16 02:31:08 MySQL-Time

Col 1       Col 2       Col 3       Col 4       Col 5       Col 6
1483221600  2016-12-31  1483225200  2017-01-01  2017-01-01  2017-01-01
1484431200  2017-01-14  1484434800  2017-01-15  2017-01-15  2017-01-15
1485813600  2017-01-30  1485817200  2017-01-31  2017-01-31  2017-01-31
1485900000  2017-01-31  1485903600  2017-02-01  2017-02-01  2017-02-01
1487109600  2017-02-14  1487113200  2017-02-15  2017-02-15  2017-02-15
1488232800  2017-02-27  1488236400  2017-02-28  2017-02-28  2017-02-28
1488319200  2017-02-28  1488322800  2017-03-01  2017-03-01  2017-03-01
1489528800  2017-03-14  1489532400  2017-03-15  2017-03-15  2017-03-15
1490911200  2017-03-31  1490911200  2017-03-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31
1490997600  2017-04-01  1490997600  2017-04-01  2017-04-01  2017-04-01
1492207200  2017-04-15  1492207200  2017-04-15  2017-04-15  2017-04-15
1493503200  2017-04-30  1493503200  2017-04-30  2017-04-30  2017-04-30
1493589600  2017-05-01  1493589600  2017-05-01  2017-05-01  2017-05-01
1494799200  2017-05-15  1494799200  2017-05-15  2017-05-15  2017-05-15
1496181600  2017-05-31  1496181600  2017-05-31  2017-05-31  2017-05-31
1496268000  2017-06-01  1496268000  2017-06-01  2017-06-01  2017-06-01
1497477600  2017-06-15  1497477600  2017-06-15  2017-06-15  2017-06-15
```

Current Time is the same Time displayed on my Computer. So it is the correct Time and the Time-Settings seem to be ok. "Current Time" is generated by the date()-Function in PHP and with MySQLs NOW().

Col 1 is the UNIX_TIMESTAMP of the MySQL-Query.

Col 2 is the Date generated with the PHP-Date-Function and Col 1.

Col 3 is the Unix Timestamp of strtotime().

Col 4 is the Date generated with the PHP-Date-Function and Col 3.

Col 5 is the Date formated with DATE_FORMAT(xdate, '%Y-%m-%d').

Col 6 is the Date directly from the database.

As you can see, the first eight Rows are wrong calculated by the date()-Function (2nd Column) which is fed with the (wrong?) UNIX_TIMESTAMP() of the MySQL-Query:

```
date('d.m.Y', $mydate)
```

I tested what happens, if I replace the line

```
 mysqli_query($db, "SET time_zone = '+02:00'");
```

with

```
 mysqli_query($db, "SET time_zone = '+01:00'");
```

The date-Function gives back the correct Date, BUT the NOW() in MySQL deliveres the wrong Time then.

When I remove the part with the Settings from the Script (see Edit 1), everything is equal, but then I have the wrong Timezone.

Has anyone a clue for me?

Comment: It's a timezone problem/difference between PHP and MySQL.

Comment: hmmm I already put timezone-settings in my settings-file.. see my edit1

Comment: @Bernhard, compare two UNIX timestamps to better understand where did it go wrong. If they are the same, the problem is in timezones. If they are different, server times are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, my Settings seem to be okay and it seems to be, that strtotime() in PHP works with Timezones in opposition to UNIX_TIMESTAMP in MySQL. I decided to replace the SELECTS which select UNIX_TIMESTAMP()s and convert it to a Timestamp with strtotime(). Now it works as it shall work.

Answer (score 2):

Expand your format to include hours and minutes, 1 gets you 10 that you are comparing LOCAL server date (according to its timezone) to UNIXTIME, which is GMT and that you are located in a timezone east of Greenwich.

Answer (score 1):

I never understand the need to recalculate a valid presented date to the number of seconds since 1970.
Certainly when afterwards these seconds are reformated to a readable date-presentation.

```
`
<?php
$dtDate = new \DateTime('2017-03-01');
echo $dtDate->format('d.m.Y');
?>
`
```

But in either case, one should be aware of the timezone settings of both the php and the database server

---

for timezone: DateTime, can have a 2nd parameter specifying the timezone

---

And as for the dates shown in the opening post: the date 31-3-2017 was the first date after the start of 2017's day light saving time (starting Sunday March 26th)
Also a reason not to assume every day has 24*60*60 seconds

Comment: the point is having a standard date that is not determined / does not favor one specific religious viewpoint.  Why is 1/1/1970 in London any worse than a winter solstice 2K+ years ago, which the christian faith chose to yearly celebrate the birth of a supposedly supernatural being on?